# How do we build custom forms in a sharepoint solution?

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

Sharepoint designer is not allowed. The forms must contain fields with references to list items but may contain custom asp controls as well, which we whish to use later in the process.
The target isn't always to replace the original new, edit and display forms but to create extra forms too. Currently, we create custom forms by copying the existing base forms and edit them by hidding the zonetemplates and add our custom fields below. It aint the most elegant way, but at the moment the best result we have so far.

I would like any suggestions.

Comment: A similar question has just been asked here: http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/27395/replacing-the-default-listforms-with-custom-aspx-pages-sharepoint-2010

Comment: How do you currently edit the forms? And what's the point of blocking SharePoint Designer if you bypass it anyway?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If developer tools ar not allowed, you might want to consider Infopath.

Also, SharePoint comes with a Form Web Part that you could include in your page.